# nodejs, mongoose looking for unique token resulting in infinite loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I'm trying to generate a random token which does not exist in the token collection. So, I'm using this check:

```
var foundToken = false;
var token;
while (!foundToken){
    token = randomstring.generate(15);
    Tokens.findOne({key: token}, function(err,res){
        if (err){
            console.log(err);
        }
        if (!res){
            foundToken = true;
        }
    });
}
```

But, on running this, randomstrings are generated in an infinite loop even when the Tokens collection is empty.

To worsen things, if I remove the second if condition, i.e

```
var foundToken = false;
var token;
while (!foundToken){
    token = randomstring.generate(15);
    Tokens.findOne({key: token}, function(err,res){
        if (err){
            console.log(err);
        }
        foundToken = true;
    });
}
```

It still results in an infinite loop so, the callback is not even executing. BTW I've already checked the randomstrings and they are totally different strings.

Comment: Do you see any errors in console log?

Comment: No, none. On console log of token, I get a list of random strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`findOne` is an asynchronous operation. Asynchronous  operations and loops do not fit well together. Put your query in a separate method with a callback parameter and don't use a while-loop.

```
var token;

getToken(function(generatedToken) {
    token = generatedToken;

    // proceed with your code
});

function getToken(callback) {
    var token = randomstring.generate(15);

    Tokens.findOne({key: token}, function(err,res){
        if (res === null) {
            // success, the token does not exist
            callback(token);
        } else {
            // token exists, try again
            getToken(callback);
        }
    });
}
```

Also take a look at [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), to avoid ending up in a [callback hell](http://callbackhell.com/).